# Python Mathematical Operation Bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Trying to perform that calculation but it fails. Is that a bug?
Python 3.10.5

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "fails"? Is it the engineering notation you're unfamiliar with? What were you _expecting_?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wasn't expecting the 1 at the end as everyone would not expect?

Comment: There is a module (decimal) which provides for floating-point arithmetic to arbitrary precision.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a bug! Your code works perfectly fine.

> ... switches to scientific notation when the values are very large or very small. For example:
>
> - 2.3e^-5, means 2.3 times ten to the minus five power, or 0.000023
> - 4.5e^6 means 4.5 times ten to the sixth power, or 4500000 which is the same as 4,500,000

[Source](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/what-does-it-mean-when-some-results-have-e-in-the-number/)